# Not able to cycle through command history while using tinker in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using the `php artisan tinker` command to do operations in Laravel.
However, I am unable to get the previous commands given while using tinker unlike other command line programs. Pressing the up or down key results in `^[[A` or `^[[B` but not the previous commands.
Is this the right behaviour for tinker?
Is there a way to get the intended function?
I am currently using Laravel 5.2.

Comment: That;s probably not an option, I missed that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have problem in your OS environment, not in Laravel itself. Could you try run the following in terminal?

```
$ php -a
Interactive mode enabled

php >
```

You should get similar response. If instead you get no prompt your PHP is compiled without `readline` support. You need to recompile it with such support turned on or install appropriate package for it.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I am able to run the command which you gave and it is properly working. However, I am unable to get command history here also. Same ^[[A or ^[[B getting on press of Up or Down key. Is there no way to enable the command history. I am using Linux Mint BTW.

Comment: Does ut show the prompt when you run `php -a` and you able to cycle through the history there?

Comment: No, I am getting ^[[A or ^[[B  on press of Up or Down key there also.

Comment: So this is it - what I described - you need to recompile your PHP with `readline` support.

Comment: Thank you, I have been able to resolve this issue by using 'readline' support.

Answer (score 0):

Just for archiving:

My problem solved by removing the `~/.config/psysh/psysh_history` file, because it had wrong owner.